# WhatsApp chatbot

Tags: facebook, chatbot, whatsapp

A client asked me to make make a WhatsApp chatbot that saves the interaction on a Google sheet but he doesn’t want me to open a Facebook account or anything other than the WhatsApp number. Is it possible? If so how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WhatsApp Cloud API to send and receive messages via your server.

Messages can be sent via an API call and responses received on a WebHook. More details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/

This does not require a new FB account per se, but you need to register as a developer.